# Flutter : Set initial Scroll offset Horizontal ListviewBuilder Depending Date

Tags: flutter

I have Card Calendar with Horizontal Direction. This card represent Total day of month , I want give initial scroll offset depend what day is it. Example this day is 7 , i want give initial scroll offset and make Card Calendar with Date **7** in center position.

[image]

I don't know the exact calculation yet to make Card with this day in center position.

My temporary way is hardcode with an incorrect formula like this .

```
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: widget.networkDateTime.day.toDouble() * 60);
    super.initState();
  }
```

But it never give me correct result if i have different Date.
How can i do this ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this package https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view

You can pass a controller and call 
`controller.jumpToIndex(widget.networkDateTime.day);`

Comment: This package not suit with my case, it will make infinite in left and right blank space, although i only have 30 card.